# A{n+1/m | n,m ∈ N} find lower and upper bound

Tags: calculus

I dont know how to solve this question. It has 2 varbs. m and n. I know only how to solve with single varb

A{n+(1/m) | n,m ∈ N}
find lower and upper bound, max and mind.

how A looks like?

please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is the set of all numbers that can be written as the sum of a natural number and a natural number's reciprocal. So, every natural number (except the smallest) is an element of $A$ (by letting $m=1$). Also, $1\frac12,2\frac12,3\frac12,\dots$ are all elements of $A.$ Likewise, $1\frac13,2\frac13,3\frac13,\dots$ are all elements of $A$, and so on for larger $m.$

Note that your problem probably asks you to find any upper/lower bounds, etc. *if they exist*, and prove it one way or another.